# pd.read_csv fails to load the first column of the csv file and file size changes when opened and saved in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to open an otherwise normal looking csv file generated by an output of a datalogger using Pandas read csv function. It is noticed that the first column of the file is not loaded into the dataframe. However, when I open the same csv file using Excel and hit save, its file size changes from 1797 Kb (original `csv`) to 1658 Kb and now when I try the same read csv function in pandas, the first column is successfully loaded into the dataframe.

I would like to know why this is happening, and if I can perform this 'function' on a batch of files without having to manually open and save large number of such csv files using Excel.

I have tried changing the encoding of the file as it gets imported into Excel, I have also tried the pd.read_excel function, but the problem persists. I have to give you the original file, otherwise, if I copy some data from the original file and save it in a new csv file, the problem disappears!

```
df=pd.read_csv("new216.csv") #Loads the csv file into a dataframe:
df.info()
```

Actual results: (Note that it says DATE column has all null objects, when in reality it has all non-null objects as seen in Excel). All other columns are fine.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 39312 entries, 0 to 39311
Data columns (total 9 columns):
DATE            0 non-null float64
TIME            39311 non-null object
TEMPERATURE     39311 non-null       float64
 PV-VOLTAGE      39311 non-null float64
 PV-CURRENT      39311 non-null float64
 BAT-VOLTAGE     39311 non-null float64
 BAT-CURRENT     39311 non-null float64
 LOAD-CURRENT    39311 non-null float64
 Unnamed: 8      0 non-null float64
 dtypes: float64(8), object(1)
 memory usage: 2.7+ MB
```

Edit_v1: Here are few lines of the csv file copied from Excel when the csv file was opened in Excel. Note that if you create a new csv with these values, it works fine, as it should. The problem lies in original csv. Stackoverflow is not giving me an option to share the original file!

```
DATE    TIME    TEMPERATURE PV-VOLTAGE  PV-CURRENT  BAT-VOLTAGE BAT-CURRENT LOAD-CURRENT
15/07/19    14:56:25    1050    49.9    8.2 49.9    -4.1    12.3
15/07/19    14:56:25    1050    49.9    8.2 49.9    -4.1    12.3
15/07/19    14:57:25    1054    49.2    3.8 49.2    -8.3    12.1
15/07/19    14:58:25    1075    49.7    7.9 49.7    -4.4    12.3
15/07/19    14:59:25    1088    49.2    3.6 49.2    -8.5    12.1
15/07/19    15:00:25    1103    49.1    3.1 49.1    -9  12.1
15/07/19    15:01:25    1114    49.1    2.9 49.1    -9.2    12.1
15/07/19    15:02:26    1131    49.1    3   49.1    -9.1    12.1
15/07/19    15:03:26    1158    49.5    6.9 49.5    -5.3    12.2
15/07/19    15:04:26    1183    49.7    8   49.7    -4.3    12.3
15/07/19    15:05:26    14  52.5    8.3 52.5    8   0.3
```

Comment: A few lines of the actual csv file would help. Copy and paste it as text then format as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I have now included the first few lines of the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
s = '''DATE    TIME    TEMPERATURE PV-VOLTAGE  PV-CURRENT  BAT-VOLTAGE BAT-CURRENT LOAD-CURRENT
15/07/19    14:56:25    1050    49.9    8.2 49.9    -4.1    12.3
15/07/19    14:56:25    1050    49.9    8.2 49.9    -4.1    12.3
15/07/19    14:57:25    1054    49.2    3.8 49.2    -8.3    12.1
15/07/19    14:58:25    1075    49.7    7.9 49.7    -4.4    12.3
15/07/19    14:59:25    1088    49.2    3.6 49.2    -8.5    12.1
15/07/19    15:00:25    1103    49.1    3.1 49.1    -9  12.1
15/07/19    15:01:25    1114    49.1    2.9 49.1    -9.2    12.1
15/07/19    15:02:26    1131    49.1    3   49.1    -9.1    12.1
15/07/19    15:03:26    1158    49.5    6.9 49.5    -5.3    12.2
15/07/19    15:04:26    1183    49.7    8   49.7    -4.3    12.3
15/07/19    15:05:26    14  52.5    8.3 52.5    8   0.3'''

f = io.StringIO(s)
```

Specifying whitespace for the Delimiter works.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+')
f.seek(0)
dg = pd.read_csv(f,delim_whitespace=True)
f.seek(0)
dh = pd.read_csv(f,delimiter='\s+')
```

One way to parse the date/time:

```
f.seek(0)
dj = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', parse_dates=[[0,1]])
```

---

Lots of options, look through the docs - [CSV & text files](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files)

---

```
In [40]: print(df.head().to_string())
       DATE      TIME  TEMPERATURE  PV-VOLTAGE  PV-CURRENT  BAT-VOLTAGE  BAT-CURRENT  LOAD-CURRENT
0  15/07/19  14:56:25         1050        49.9         8.2         49.9         -4.1          12.3
1  15/07/19  14:56:25         1050        49.9         8.2         49.9         -4.1          12.3
2  15/07/19  14:57:25         1054        49.2         3.8         49.2         -8.3          12.1
3  15/07/19  14:58:25         1075        49.7         7.9         49.7         -4.4          12.3
4  15/07/19  14:59:25         1088        49.2         3.6         49.2         -8.5          12.1

In [42]: print(dj.head().to_string())
            DATE_TIME  TEMPERATURE  PV-VOLTAGE  PV-CURRENT  BAT-VOLTAGE  BAT-CURRENT  LOAD-CURRENT
0 2019-07-15 14:56:25         1050        49.9         8.2         49.9         -4.1          12.3
1 2019-07-15 14:56:25         1050        49.9         8.2         49.9         -4.1          12.3
2 2019-07-15 14:57:25         1054        49.2         3.8         49.2         -8.3          12.1
3 2019-07-15 14:58:25         1075        49.7         7.9         49.7         -4.4          12.3
4 2019-07-15 14:59:25         1088        49.2         3.6         49.2         -8.5          12.1
```